# Saving Depth. Normals and Material index?

Tags: scripting

After rendering in a script, I am trying to save the Depth, Normals and Material Index along with the colored image.

I found I can save selected layers by saving an OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER file, like this:

```
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.exr_codec = 'ZIP'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_depth = '32'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGB'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_zbuffer = True

#All layers that we want in the EXR files
bpy.context.view_layer.cycles.denoising_store_passes = False
layer=bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"]
layer.use_pass_ambient_occlusion=False
layer.use_pass_combined=False
layer.use_pass_diffuse_color=True
layer.use_pass_diffuse_direct=True
layer.use_pass_diffuse_indirect=True
layer.use_pass_emit=False
layer.use_pass_environment=False
layer.use_pass_glossy_color=False
layer.use_pass_glossy_direct=False
layer.use_pass_glossy_indirect=False
layer.use_pass_material_index=True
layer.use_pass_mist=False
layer.use_pass_normal=True
layer.use_pass_object_index=True
layer.use_pass_shadow=False
layer.use_pass_subsurface_color=False
layer.use_pass_subsurface_direct=False
layer.use_pass_subsurface_indirect=False
layer.use_pass_transmission_color=False
layer.use_pass_transmission_direct=False
layer.use_pass_transmission_indirect=False
layer.use_pass_uv=False
layer.use_pass_vector=False
layer.use_pass_z=True
layer.use_sky=False
layer.use_solid=False
layer.use_strand=False
layer.use_zmask=True
layer.use_ztransp=True

bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

The problem is, the layers I turn off is used internally to render the image properly. If I turn them off, the image is rendered wrong. Probably end up black or with the wrong shading.

So, why not just enable all the layers? Well, turns out the files become huge. Typically 1GB or more in compressed form, for 4096x2048 renders. And we will render thousands of images. So, I really want to remove that uneccessary weight.

Is there a way to do this? Or, another way to save only the selected layers?